# webview (assets) doesn't respect the device width

Tags: php, android, webview, viewport, assets

A month ago i did a simple webview that called a web page (php) in which there was this:

```
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

But now i've done the same thing but offline, viz the same files in the assets folder and i called them (index.php that includes header.php and footer.php) all in local), also the css file and js files using the webview function loadurl > "file:///android_asset/index.php".
I've tried on my device (samsung galaxy s2) and its ok, run, but it doesn't load the css or the header.php.
SOmeone could help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android device does not have a PHP intepreter / apacheserver inside to execute the PHP code and output the generated HTML. (So the include commands wont work)
You have to include a plain HTML page in your assets folder or load a php page from a server... (not local)

To try it locally you can save the HTML page generated by the server from the online version with your browser and put that page in the assets folder. But that is useless when your page is dynamic.

Comment: ok perfect, now run perfectly, but it's normal that is slower than loading a webview from the internet? I thought that if i had loaded a page from local, it would have relieved it, but it's worse than before.

Answer (score 0):

You need LocalServer installed on your Android for this issue, it is a easy job, just search for AndroPhp in GooglePLay install it on your Android, this way you have a LocalServer with MySQL db.

Then just copy your PHP project under www/ forlder ofcourse if you have db you shoul import in to MySQl on your Android.

on Android side call call it than 127.0.0.1:80/yourproject